# Convert .txt file to .xlsx & remove unneeded rows & format columns correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a folder which contains .txt files (they contain PHI, so I can't upload the .txt file, or an example without PHI, or even any images of it). I need an excel macro, which will allow the user to choose the folder containing the file, and will then insert the .txt file data into a new excel workbook, format the rows and columns appropriately, and finally save the file to the same folder that the source was found in. 
So far I've got all of that working except for the formatting of rows and columns. As of now, the .txt data is inserted to a new workbook & worksheet, but I can't seem to figure out how to get rid of rows I don't need, or how to get the columns formatted appropriately.

Again, I can't upload the .txt file (or anything) because the Healthcare organization I work for blocks it - even if I've removed all PHI.

Below is the macro I've created so far:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    On Error GoTo err

    'Allow the user to choose the FOLDER where the TEXT file(s) are located
    'The resulting EXCEL file will be saved in the same location
        Dim FldrPath As String
        Dim fldr As FileDialog
        Dim fldrChosen As Integer

        Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fldr
            .Title = "Select a Folder containing the Text File(s)"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .InitialFileName = "\\FILELOCATION"
            fldrChosen = .Show

            If fldrChosen <> -1 Then
                MsgBox "You Chose to Cancel"
            Else
                FldrPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If

        End With


    If FldrPath <> "" Then

        'Make a new workbook
            Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
            Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add

        'Make worksheet1 of new workbook active
            newWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate


        'Completed files are saved in the chosen source file folder
               Dim CurrentFile As String: CurrentFile = Dir(FldrPath & "\" & "*.txt")
               Dim strLine() As String
               Dim LineIndex As Long

               Application.ScreenUpdating = False
               Application.DisplayAlerts = False
               While CurrentFile <> vbNullString
                   'How many rows to place in Excel ABOVE the data we are inserting
                   LineIndex = 0
                   Close #1
                   Open FldrPath & "\" & CurrentFile For Input As #1
                   While Not EOF(1)
                        'Adds number of rows below the inserted row of data
                        LineIndex = LineIndex + 1

                        ReDim Preserve strLine(1 To LineIndex)
                        Line Input #1, strLine(LineIndex)

                   Wend
                   Close #1

                   With ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Resize(LineIndex, 1)
                       .Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(strLine)
                       .TextToColumns Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
                   End With

                   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                   ActiveSheet.Name = Replace(CurrentFile, ".txt", "")
                    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FldrPath & "\" & Replace(CurrentFile, ".txt", ".xls"), xlNormal
                   ActiveWorkbook.Close

                   CurrentFile = Dir
               Wend
               Application.DisplayAlerts = True
               Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

    Done:
        Exit Sub

    err:
        MsgBox "The following ERROR Occurred:" & vbNewLine & err.Description
        ActiveWorkbook.Close


    End Sub
```

Any ideas of how I can delete entire lines from being brought into excel? 
And how I can format the columns appropriately? So that I'm not getting 3 columns from the .txt file all jammed into 1 column in the resulting excel file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you not to re-invent the wheel. Microsoft provides an excellent add-on to accomplish this task, Power Query.

It lets you to load every file in a folder and process it in bulks.
[Here you have a brief introduction of what can do for you.](https://www.excelcampus.com/powerquery/power-query-overview/)

Comment: I appreciate the feedback; however, I'm not allowed admin rights and therefore cannot download any add-ins.